# PHP soap extension dont work with php 8 alpine with Dockerfile

Tags: php, soap, dockerfile, php-extension

I try to run composer install, but i dont have `soap` extension:

```
Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.
    
Problem 1
   - Root composer.json requires PHP extension ext-soap * but it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's soap extension.
    
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
   - /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
   - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-intl.ini
   - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini
   - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini
   - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_pgsql.ini
   - /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-sodium.ini
```

My Dockerfile parts:

```
    FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine
    RUN set -eux; \
        apk update; \
        apk add php-soap; \

    RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev; \
        docker-php-ext-install soap; \
        docker-php-ext-enable soap; \
```

I dont get any errors on build docker-compose.. Other extensions are OK. Only `soap` have problem.

I try also `FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine3.15` and other extension names like `php8-soap`/`php-soap`.

I also tried using https://github.com/codecasts/php-alpine - no effect

Comment: Debug from container: for `find / -name *soap.so` outpu:

`/usr/lib/php7/modules/soap.so`

for `php --ini`
output: 
`Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-intl.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-opcache.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_mysql.ini,
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-pdo_pgsql.ini,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working version:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine3.15

RUN set -eux; \
    apk update; \
    apk add libxml2-dev; \
    apk add php8-soap; \


RUN apk add --no-cache postgresql-dev; \
    docker-php-ext-install soap; \
    docker-php-ext-enable soap; \
```